# Subdirectory Multi Store Issue

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I am trying to figure out these multi store in sub directories deal.  I am using version 1.8.1.

Here is what one of my sub-stores looks like: http://hypeforce.com/lab/shirts/   I feel like I am getting close but for some reason its not picking up on the formatting.

The edits I made to the subdir index.php were:

> $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';

and

> $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ?
> $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'shirts1';

^^ That was for my sub store code

I am not sure what else to post.    I did all the steps outlined here:
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html

Please help!   I am even willing to send some paypal bucks to understand why this is happening so I don't do this moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set your different store views in System > Manage stores, go to System > Configuration > Design. There switch between each store views using the scope select on the left.

You will have to enter your interface name (eg : mycompany), and then in the "Themes" tab, untick "Use default value" for the field "By default", and enter the name of your folder (eg: myviewname). Save and go to your FTP.

### app/design/

There you'll have to go to `app/design/frontend/`, create a folder named after your interface name (here : mycompany), go in that folder and create another folder name after your default design name (here : myviewname). Then go in that folder and create 3 folders (etc, layout and template).

You will be able to override template folders by copying the exact structure if the files into your "myviewname" folder (from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`).

When Magento is unable to find a template in your custom defined folders, it will look into the base folder (`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`).

### skin/

Do the same thing for the skin/ folder. Create the same base structure (skin/frontend/mycompany/myviewname/ and copy/paste the files from skin/frontend/base/default. This is where you will put your custom CSS's, which you should call in your app/design/frontend/mycompany/myviewname/layout/page.xml 's header section.

Comment: ok so I tried that, but it still did not work for me.  I may be doing something wrong though.

So my subdir site is called "shirts" with storecode of "shirts1"  - so when I go to app/design/frontend am I making it /app/design/frontend/shirts/shirts ?   or just one level?  

After that, am I copying the existing contents of app/design/frontend/base/default/template to my newly created folders?

Comment: just read it again, I thin I made it pretty clear. I don't think it's clever to name the subdirectory the same way you named its parent though ;) it is explained in my 2nd §

Comment: Well, this still doesn't work and I have been at it for HOURS.   I think lots of folks are basing their directions on an older version of magento - every option I come across is drastically different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the symbolic links to your skin, templates, var etc. A symbolic link is a pointer to another file or directory. It can be used just like the original file or directory.

You would accomplish this via SSH as seen below.

`ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/app
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/includes/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/includes
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/js/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/js
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/lib
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/media/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/media
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/skin/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/skin
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ /home/example/example.com/html/secondarydir/var`

More information on setting up multiple store fronts can be found at http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/

Quick edit because I see the code is wrapping, an example of the link would be as below:

`ln -s /from/direcotry/var/ /to/directory/var`

Comment: Would that process via SSH be necessary if I am having subdirectory  stores on the same domain?

Comment: The symbolic links just ensure that you don't have to place additional copies of those folders/files inside the subdirectory. This way, when you make a modification to the main store/theme it will be automatically present in any of your secondary stores using the same template/skin.